# Why C# anonymous type can't be used when declaring constants?

Tags: c#, error-handling, constants

```
private const object foo = new {Prop1 = 10, Prop2 = 20};
```

This code will output the error CS0836: `Anonymous types cannot be used in this expression`. But if you remove `const` it will run ok.

I'm really just trying to understand. Why can't anonymous type be used in constant declarations?

More specifically: What other way should be used to declare a constant like that?

Answer (score 7):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx)

> Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference

So the fact that there's an anonymous type here is not relevant: if you were using a custom class you would get a similar error.

Consider using a `static readonly` field instead of `const` for these cases.

That said, having a field of type `object` in this situation is questionable: no-one who references the field is going to be able to access `Prop1` or `Prop2`, so the field is arguably useless.

Consider defining a custom `class` (not an anonymous type) which contains your two properties, and using that instead, e.g. `private static readonly Foo foo = new Foo(10, 20);`

Comment: You could access the properties through reflection, so it may not be as useless as you say.

Comment: It's true, hence why I said "arguably". Using an anonymous type + reflection instead of just a custom type would be considered bad practice though.

Comment: Yes, that looks like a code smell indeed. I can think of *one* acceptable use case though: to pass this object to a method such as [`InputExtensions.TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493049.aspx) that accepts an `object` argument and then turns its properties to HTML attributes.

Comment: That's fair enough! Though I might expect to see that anonymous type declared inline in the view rather than as a const in some model.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, in c# you can declare as constants only a set of predefined primitive types: more details you can find here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx. An anonymous type is just an immutable reference type that is written automatically by the compiler so it is just like a normal reference type that you can write anytime.